# Azure LogicApp deployment returns BadRequest with "multiple errors"

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

Deployment stack trace returns "System.FormatException: unable to decrypt [readacted FunctionApp host key value]; the key is either malformed or invalid". One error is generated for each referenced Azure function.

Comment: Do the function apps have slots enabled? There is a known issue with logic apps + functions with slots

Comment: Could you post your ARM template ??